# How to apply css style from successive classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need, when the `.checked` class is present, to insert `text-decoration: line-through;` style to `.todo-name`

(I never understood if it is possible to do it with css, but in case I can also use js as a last chance)

```
<label class="checkbox-container" for="0"><span class="todo-name">Todo</span>
    <input onclick="updateStatus(this)" type="checkbox" id="0" checked="">
    <span class="checkmark checked"></span>
</label>

<!--This content does not have .checked and should not change-->
<label class="checkbox-container" for="0"><span class="todo-name">Todo</span>
    <input onclick="updateStatus(this)" type="checkbox" id="0">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<style>
/*.todo-name{text-decoration: line-through;}*/


/*Not working*/
/*
.checkbox-container .checked ~ .todo-name {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.checkbox-container:not(.checked) .todo-name {text-decoration: line-through;}
*/
</style>
```

[Codepen project](https://codepen.io/marcogattone/pen/yLqRPoN)

The end result should look like this [image: End Result]

Comment: I think you’ve got `.checked` and `:checked` mixed up. The first is a CSS class, the second is a pseudo-class. Try using `:checked` instead and don’t use a normal CSS class.

Comment: No confusion, I have js code that adds this class to make everything work, that's why I have the need for it to be a class and not a pseudo-class.

But the basic question could also apply to a simple div,: Can a css class act from bottom to top (and not vice versa as it does). (I know this is counterintuitive because the very meaning of css is "Cascading Style Sheets.")

Comment: In the future include all your code so we can see the big picture, otherwise we’re just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple issues going on here. As mentioned in a comment, you should be using a pseudo-class, if you don't want to use JavaScript. `:checked` in this example.

Next, you are using the CSS selector `~`, which selects a sibling that comes after the element, not before. So trying to select `.todo-name` with the selector `#0:checked ~ .todo-name` will not work due to the name coming before the checkbox.

Below is an example of a working version.

```css
input:checked ~ .todo-name {
    text-decoration: line-through;  
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-container" for="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="">
    <span class="todo-name">Todo</span>
</label>

<label class="checkbox-container" for="checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    <span class="todo-name">Todo</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Can a css class act from bottom to top (and not vice versa as it happens) , the definitive answer is no.
(I know it is counterintuitive because the very meaning of css is "Cascading Style Sheets")

The ones you found are great solutions, thank you very much!